# PDFs: Extracting text associated with font (linux)

Tags: pdf, fonts, text-extraction

The general problem that I'm trying to solve is to determine how much text in a large set of PDFs is associated with different fonts.  I know I can extract text from a PDF using pdftotext and fonts information with pdffonts, but I can't figure out how to link those together.  I have 100,000+ PDFs to process, so will need something I can program against (and I don't mind a commercial solution).

Comment: I'm not trying to be patronizing, but have you tried searching Google yet?

Answer (score 0):

[PDFTron PDFNet SDK](https://www.pdftron.com/pdf-sdk/parsing-library) can extract all the graphic operations, including text objects, including link to the font being used.

Starting with the ElementReader sample, you can get the Font for every text element.
https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/samples?platforms=windows#elementreader
https://www.pdftron.com/api/PDFNet/?topic=html/T_pdftron_PDF_Font.htm

Comment: Thanks for this information.  I ended up using the pdf2text tool included with PDFTron with XML output and styles (pdf2text -f xml --xml_output_styles).  This contained the font information per line of text, which I could then quantify.

Answer (score 0):

The [Adobe PDF Library](https://www.datalogics.com/products/pdf/pdflibrary/) - a product my company sells - can do that.

This is part of the sample code:

```
// This callback function is called fpr each PDWord object.
ACCB1 ASBool ACCB2 WordEnumProc(PDWordFinder wfObj, PDWord pdWord, ASInt32 pgNum, void* clientData)
{
    char str[128];
    char fontname[100];

    // get word text
    PDWordGetString(pdWord, str, sizeof(str));

    // get the font name
    PDStyle style = PDWordGetNthCharStyle(wfObj, pdWord, 0);
    PDFont wordFont = PDStyleGetFont(style);
    PDFontGetName(wordFont, fontname, sizeof(fontname));

    printf("%s  [%s]\n", str, fontname);

    return true;
}
```

This is the output example:

```
...
Chapter  [Arial,Bold]
2:  [Arial,Bold]
Overview  [Arial,Bold]
27  [Arial]
...
This  [TimesNewRoman]
book  [TimesNewRoman]
describes  [TimesNewRoman]
the  [TimesNewRoman]
Portable  [TimesNewRoman]
Document  [TimesNewRoman]
Format  [TimesNewRoman]
...
```